# trying to create a chat "template" for my chatbot

Tags: python, chatbot

I am trying to create a template for my chat bot so the chat looks like

`carl: my name is carl, what is yours?`

`user: *some response*`

I have no issues with the bot template, but where my issue is coming by is when I try to create the users template, it gives me an error saying "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'function' and 'str'"

```
# templates
def templates():
    user = myname
    print(user + ':')

# asking your name
def myname():
    print('carl: my name is carl, what is yours?')
    myname = input()
    templates()
    print('carl: nice to meet you ' + myname)
```

if anyone has any advice, would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
def templates(user):
    print(user + ': *some response*')

def myname():
    print('carl: my name is carl, what is yours?')
    user = input()
    templates(user)
    print('carl: nice to meet you ' + user)

myname()
```

Your problem is that you make a function called `myname` and also make a variable called `myname`, among other things.

Answer (score 1):

NEVER! EVER! Use the a variable name as a function name. Just change the variable name to UsersName = input();